# Dynamically adding dom elements based on click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html, dom

I have two buttons as **Image** and **Text**. based on click of these buttons I want to dynamically add an element to the dom i.e. either TextArea or ImageArea.

Since my HTML code is very lengthy I cant use nativeElement.append(var);

What approach should I use now to append my elements dynamically to the dom.

Comment: what did you try so far that didn't work?

Comment: You can make images and texts as an array and use ngFor to generate more images or texts. You have to add a value to an array based on your button click.

Comment: I tried using nativeElement.append(var); but since my markup for text or image is almost of 80 line, So I dont want to store all the markup in var

Answer (score 0):

a correct answer depends on the architecture of your application and what you exactly need. Angular provides many ways to add elements to the DOM. The easiest and what probably solve your problem, is to just use `*ngIf`, for example:

```
// component.ts

showImage: boolean = false;

// component.html

<img src="img.jpg" *ngIf="showImage">
<button (click)="showImage=true">Show image</button>
```

If you want to add several elements to DOM, you can use `*ngFor`:

```
// component.ts

images: any[] = [];

addImage() {
  this.images.push(this.images.length+1);
}

removeImage() {
  this.images.pop();
}

// component.html

<img src="img.jpg" *ngFor="let img of images">
<button (click)="addImage()">Show an image more</button>
<button (click)="removeImage()">Show an image less</button>
```

---

**Edit:**

```
// component.ts

imagesAndTextarea: string[] = [];

addImg() {
  this.imagesAndTextarea.push('img');
}

addTextarea() {
  if (this.iamgesAndTexarea.filter(x => x === 'textarea').length >= 12) return;
  this.imagesAndTextarea.push('textarea');
}

// template.html

<ng-container *ngFor="let el of imagesAndTextarea">
  <textarea .... *ngIf="el === 'textarea'">
  <img .... *ngIf="el === 'img'">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Currently I am using the exact same thing. But this is making my markup static.e.g  <img src="img.jpg" *ngIf="showImage1"> <textarea *ngIf="showText1"></textarea>         <img src="img.jpg" *ngIf="showImage2"> <textarea *ngIf="showText2"></textarea>       Now if I add two text area then one image area The Image area will be in between of two textarea. Ideally it should append in the end

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic markup? Do you have a set of possible elements? If no, why?

Comment: Yes I have a set of possible elements. User can add six textarea and six imagearea . Total Areas that can be added = 12

Comment: imagearea is angular-2-image-upload Area its not individuall image to use array

Comment: @Cristiam Traina by your edit I wont be able to use my bindings with component since each area has different bindigs

Comment: How can I bind values if I use your approach. I.e. <textarea [value]="textarea1value"></textarea> <textarea [value]="textarea2value"></textarea> <textarea [value]="textarea3value"></textarea>....so on , similarly for imagearea I have sevral bindings